# How to create a word document from PHP form input and save it in a file

Tags: php

I have a form page

index.php

```
<form name="proposal_form" action="<?php echo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%"> 
          <tr> 
            <td width="23%" class="body"> Name</td> 
            <td width="3%" class="body">:</td> 
            <td width="74%"><input type="text" name="strname" class="textfield"></td> 
        </tr> 


      </table>    
  <input type="submit" name="submit_docs" value="Export as MS Word" class="input-button" />
</form>

<?php


  if(isset($_POST['submit_docs'])){
 $doc_body ='
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%"> 
          <tr> 
            <td width="23%" class="body"> Name</td> 
            <td width="3%" class="body">:</td> 
            <td width="74%">'.$_POST["strname"].'</td> 
        </tr> 

      </table>    
 ';}

  header("Content-Type: application/vnd.msword");
  header("Expires: 0");//no-cache
  header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");//no-cache
 header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=sampleword.doc"); 
 //store in local file
file_put_contents( "/files/sample.doc",$doc_body);
 ?>
```

I am trying to create a word  file when the form is submitted But its not showing in the Folder.

Any idea where I am doing mistake

Comment: In what folder you could not find the file? On server or you expect to see at at the user computer?

Comment: You need to output only the file contents after setting headers. Now you've got wrong order and unneeded form (when you are trying to make a doc file).

Comment: @VladimirSerykh on my server , if I echo the variable `$doc_body` then I get the word file in user computer

Comment: @VladimirSerykh can you guide me How I can create this file and save on my server so that I can send it as an attachment in email .

Comment: Sorry, could not help with doc. But if there is no file at all, you need to check your paths and permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in PHP to save as a Word document. Just use your values instead of the examples I have put in them.

```
<?php
$value1 = $_POST['Name'];
$value2 = $_POST['Phone'];
$value3 = $_POST['State1'];
$value4 = $_POST['MemberID'];
$value5 = $_POST['TaxID'];
$value6 = $_POST['UserID'];
$value7 = $_POST['Facility'];
$value8 = $_POST['Email'];
$value9 = $_POST['AdditionalNotes'];


header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=PSSD.doc");

echo "<html>";
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">";
echo "<body>";
echo "<b><i>Name:</i> ".$value1."</b> \t \t \n <br>";
echo "<b><i>Phone#:</i> ".$value2."</b> \t \t \n <br>";
echo "<b><i>State:</i> ".$value3."</b> \t \t \n <br>";
echo "<b><i>Member ID:</i>".$value4."</b> \t \t \n <br>";
echo "<b><i>Tax ID: </i>".$value5."</b> \t \t \n <br>";
echo "<b><i>User ID:</i> ".$value6."</b> \t \t \n <br>";
echo "<b><i>Facility: </i>".$value7."</b> \t \t \n <br>";`enter code here`
echo "<b><i>Email: </i>".$value8."</b> \t \t \n <br>";
echo "<b><i>Additional Notes: </i>".$value9."</b> \t \t \n <br>";

echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```